# Archive iOS application using caches from DerivedData

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, fastlane

I'm using Fastlane for my CI builds on Github Actions.

CI runs Fastlane's `build_app` function. The `build_app` internally uses `xcodebuild archive` to archive the project and then uses `xcodebuild -exportArchive` to extract `IPA`.

The problem is `xcodebuild archive` always ignores caches and builds all the modules from the source (even if DerivedData from previous builds are available). Is there a way to force either `fastlane` or `xcodebuild archive` to use caches from `DerivedData`. Or maybe there is some other way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?

Comment: @skeg0 unfortunately not. I'm thinking there is no way to achieve this with `archive` tool.